# ARCore will recognize the floor and try to stop the plane recognition after creating the object

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, arcore

In the ARCore tutorial, if you recognize a plane with the camera and touch it, you will create an object, and if you recognize another plane, you can create another object there.
However, I want to recognize one plane and create an object, then stop the plane recognition and hide the already recognized range at the same time.

The algorithm is as follows:
Recognize the floor -> Create the object by touching the recognized range -> Stop the plane recognition, hide the first recognized range, and leave only the object.

I have succeeded in creating only one object and preventing the creation of additional objects.
But I do not know how I should touch the code anymore ... Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop plane recognition, you have to access the ARCore session config

```
// If you are using ARCore 1.2
FindObjectOfType<ARCoreSession>().SessionConfig.PlaneFindingMode = DetectedPlaneFindingMode.Disabled;

// If you are using a previous ARCore version
FindObjectOfType<ARCoreSession>().SessionConfig.EnablePlaneFinding = false;
```

To hide the already tracked planes, you need to find them and disable their mesh renderer. In ARCore, you could do something like this (I have not tested this)

```
DetectedPlaneVisualizer[] detectedPlanes = FindObjectsOfType<DetectedPlaneVisualizer>();
for(int i = 0; i < detectedPlanes.Length; i++)
{
    detectedPlanes[i].transform.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
}
```

However, you could use an [ARCore plugin](https://github.com/VR-House/Eazy-ARCore-Interface) I wrote to make development easier. With that, you can just use one line of code to disable tracked planes

```
EazyARCoreInterface.VisualizeDetectedPlanes = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I stopped the plane recognition, and the objects that I had previously created came out for a while and then disappeared. DontDestroyOnLoad also seems to have no effect. Is there any way?

Comment: What exactly did you try? That seems like strange behaviour. Also, DontDestroyOnLoad has nothing to do with this, so it will definitely not help.

Comment: Desired algorithm
Plane Recognition with ARCore -> Create Object with Touch in Recognized Space -> Remove original recognition range created after creating one object (object remains) -> No additional floor is recognized.

Current state algorithm
Plane Recognition with ARCore -> Create Objects with Touch in Recognized Space -> Recognized Planes and Objects Disappear Immediately -> No additional floor is recognized.

Comment: All I want to do is to have the first recognized object, but that does not work.
DontDestroyOnLoad was intended to keep the object from being erased, but it was not appropriate.
If I remove the perceived range, the objects that were created on it seem to disappear as well.
If I am right, can I hide the recognized range after creating the object?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: yes, I added it to the tutorial's HelloARController.cs script.
Add a variable called MaximumObject and currentlyObject
if (MaximumObject> currentlyObject)
                {
                    currentlyObject = currentlyObject + 1;
I added this code so that if an object was not created, I could create only one
[TrackbleHit since declaring hit andyObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;]
I wrote down the code you wrote down in the code [FindObjectOfType <ARCoreSession> (). SessionConfig.EnablePlaneFinding = false;]
However, this is not working as desired.